# Does it make sense to implement an API call for stats on a dashboard page?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm adding a page on my site that is kind of an overview of all the other data. It will include stuff like total X (rows), number of registered users, number of unregistered users, total number of users with x property, etc. I was thinking of doing an api route that returns an object with key/value pairs that are exactly the stats that I need (doing this instead of, say, fetching all the data and aggregating it on the front-end, since, I would assume, doing a COUNT in SQL is going to be a lot faster). Does it make sense to implement such a route? Or is this poor design? This route would likely be called on an interval, like every 30 seconds or something.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing that, especially for an internal-facing API.

Comment: @EricStein why would it be "especially" appropriate internal-facing API?

Comment: Because with an external-facing API you're in trouble when your biggest customer wants more/different data and your other 25 customers don't want it to change. With an internal-facing API you're the only consumer, so there's much less pain to changing - you control both sides of the equation, not just one.